# Apply character limit on formview control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, formview

I have the following formview and need to apply a character limit to the htmleditor. After looking around, there is no built in support for this. I'm attempting to use jquery to apply the limit, but haven't been able to figure out the selector to target the htmleditor.

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvWebDescription" CssClass="webdescription" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id, type" 
                        DataSourceID="sdsWebVisitorsDescription">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <custom:CustomEditor ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("content") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" 
                                 Text="Update" /> | <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <custom:CustomEditor ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("content") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" /> | <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="contentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("content") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" OnCommand="loadDescription" CommandArgument="web" />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>This business does not have a description for website visitors. Please 
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="New" Text="click here" /> to add one.</EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:FormView>
```

The form view generates an iframe with and puts the text in a body tag. The iframe is dynamically generated when the user clicks an edit button, which is default behavior, nothing special. but this is why I can't simply target the control with a simple id selector.

To complicate things, if using jquery, I have to use jquery 1.4.2.

I've tried many variations of this...

```
 $(document).delegate(('.webdescription body'), "click", function () {
                            console.log(this).text();
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To traverse an iframe with jquery that's the code:

```
$("#fvWebDescription").contents().find("selector").hide();
```

with this snippet you can add an handler on your form.